# Scrapy error " AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'xpath' "

Tags: python, scrapy, attributeerror

When I try the scrapy shell, I have some problems can not solve.

> In [1]: response.xpath('//title')
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 response.xpath('//title')
>   AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Anyone can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you should upgrade scrapy

Steps:
1.download Scrapy 0.24.6
http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Scrapy/Scrapy-0.24.6.tar.gz

2.Uncompress Files

3.and then:
F:\Scrapy-0.24.6>python setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade the Scrapy, I solve the problem